# Como verificar se uma variável é float, decimal ou inteiro em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, tipagem, números

Tentei com `typeof()`, porem ele só me retorna se é um número, *string*, etc.

Seria algo assim:

```
var x = 1.2;

if (x == inteiro){
    alert("x é um inteiro");
}
```

Comment: Obviamente as perguntas não são duplicatas, é só lê-las.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação da MDN existem alguns poucos tipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). O tipo numérico não faz distinção se ele é inteiro, decimal ou possuem ponto decimal binário. Então não tem como obter esta informação. E de forma geral isto é irrelevante.

A [documentação do `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) deixa claro quais os retornos possíveis.

```
undefined
boolean
number
string
symbol
function
object
Outros dependendo da implementação do JavaScript.
```

O que dá para fazer é verificar se um valor tem uma parte decimal ou não, pegando o resto:

```js
var x = 1.2;
if (x % 1 === 0) console.log("x é um inteiro");
var y = 10;
if (y % 1 === 0) console.log("y é um inteiro");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/ComparingType.js).

Na versão 6 no EcmaScript, que poucos navegadores suportam ainda, pode-se usar o [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). Ele pode ser simulado assim:

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && 
           isFinite(value) && 
           Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

Comment: Realmente, pelo que verifiquei não tem como fazer de uma maneira fácil tal condição verificando se é uma variável do tipo float, double. Queria apenas saber se tinha como fazer isso. Mas muito obrigado pela resposta :D

Comment: Sou iniciante no stack, daí estou apanhando pra mexer nele ainda kkk.

Answer (score 9):

Aqui fica uma sugestão, para dar uma ideia de como poderias fazer:

```
// string, float, decimal ou inteiro em javascript
function tipo(nr) {
    if (typeof nr == 'string' && nr.match(/(\d+[,.]\d+)/)) return 'string decimal';
    else if (typeof nr == 'string' && nr.match(/(\d+)/)) return 'string inteiro';
    else if (typeof nr == 'number') return nr % 1 == 0 ? 'numero inteiro' : 'numero decimal';
    else return false;
}

var testes = [10, 5.5, '10', '5.5', 'virus'].map(tipo);
console.log(testes);
// dá: ["numero inteiro", "numero decimal", "string inteiro", "string decimal", false]
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6rtg24v/2

No fundo verifica se é do tipo `String` ou `Number` e caso é decimal ou inteiro. Na regex coloquei virgula e ponto como opção, mas podes remover um deles se tiveres certeza das strings que vais receber.